# PowerShell's parsing modes: argument (command) mode vs. expression mode

Tags: powershell, parsing, syntax

Can anyone explain why when returning $false from a powershell function you are unable use a comparison operator to determine if the function has returned $false but when you return $true the comparison evaluates to $true?

```
function boolean {
    return $false
}

boolean -eq $false

function boolean {
    return $true
}

boolean -eq $true

>>>False
>>>True
```

You can work around this by setting the function call to a variable, but I was wondering if anyone could explain what is happening here under the hood?

```
function boolean {
    return $false
}

$bool = boolean 
$bool -eq $false

function boolean {
    return $true
}

$bool = boolean
$bool -eq $true

>>>True
>>>True
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PowerShell has ***two* fundamental parsing modes**:

- ***argument* mode**, which works like traditional *shells*

  - In argument mode, the **first token is interpreted as a *command name*** (such as cmdlet name,  function name, or filename of a script or external executable), **followed by a *whitespace-separated list* of *arguments***.
- ***expression* mode**, which works like traditional *programming languages*.

Running [`Get-help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) provides an introduction to these modes; in short, **it is the *first token* that determines which mode is applied.**
Also note that a given statement may be composed of parts that are parsed in either mode.

---

**`boolean -eq $false` is parsed in *argument* mode**, because its **first token looks like a *command name*** (an identifier that could be a program name, cmdlet name, function name, or alias).

Therefore, **`-eq` and `$false` are interpreted as *arguments* (parameter values) to pass to function `boolean`**.

Since your `boolean` functions are defined in a way that doesn't enforce passing values only to *declared* parameters, the arguments are effectively *ignored*, and the result of the statement is whatever the functions output (`$false` or `$true`).

As demonstrated in [Mike Shepard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48776419/45375), **you can make a function enforce use of only *declared* parameters (including *none*) with a `param()` block decorated with the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute** (which makes the function an [*advanced* function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Methods)), which would at least result in an error if you inadvertently passed arguments to the parameter-less `boolean` function.

---

> You can work around this by setting the function call to a variable

```sh
$bool = boolean   # execute function and capture result in variable
$bool -eq $false  # use variable in the comparison
```

The reason this works is that the `-eq` statement *starts with `$`* - a variable reference in this case - which causes PowerShell to parse in *expression* mode, where `-eq` is recognized as an *operator* and `$false` as its RHS.

However, there is no need for this intermediate step:

To **force a piece of code to be interpreted as an *expression*, enclose it in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)**:

```sh
(boolean) -eq $false # Calls function 'boolean' and uses result as LHS of -eq
```

**`(...)` forces a new parsing context** (which in itself is parsed in either argument or expression mode, again depending on the 1st token) and **treats the result as an *expression***. which then **allows its use as part of a larger expression**, such as as an operand of the `-eq` operator, **or as a command argument**.

Answer (score 10):

PowerShell is seeing -eq as the name of a parameter being passed to the "boolean" function.

To see this, you can put the function call in parens:

```
function boolean {
    return $false
}

(boolean) -eq $false

function boolean {
    return $true
}

(boolean) -eq $true
```

Or, you can make it an advanced function so you get an error with the missing parameter (-eq):

```
function boolean {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
    return $false
}

boolean -eq $false

function boolean {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
    return $true
}

boolean -eq $true
```