# Powershell function unexpectedly returns no object

Tags: powershell, syntax, control-flow

I want to have in a .ps1 file some code that creates a PSSession that can be used in other .ps1 scripts (in order to avoid code duplication).

At first I thought i need a function that creates a PSSession and returns it but I am confused about how they the function outputs work.

Here is my function:

```
function newRemoteSession
{
    param([string]$ipAddress)

    $accountName = 'admin'
    $accountPassword = 'admin'
    $accountPasswordSecure = ConvertTo-SecureString $accountPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $accountCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($accountName, $accountPasswordSecure)

    Try
    {
        $remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ipAddress -UseSSL -Credential $accountCredential -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck) -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] #PSRemotingTransportException
    {
        Write-Host 'Could not connect with default credentials. Please enter credentials...'    
        $remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ipAddress -UseSSL -Credential (Get-Credential) -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck) -ErrorAction Stop
        Break
    }

    return $remoteSession
}
```

However when I call `$s = newRemoteSession(192.168.1.10)`, `$s` is empty.

When I run a script with

```
Write-Host '00'
$s = newRemoteSession('192.168.1.10')
$s
Write-Host '02'

function newRemoteSession
{
        ........
    Write-Host '01'
    $remoteSession
}
```

I get only '00' in the console, but I know the function runs because I get the credential prompt.

EDIT:

Ok, now it works:

- The Break in the Catch was stopping everything.
- The function call must be without parenthesis.
- The second code was wrong because the function must be defined before the call.

Comment: If you place the function in the same file where you are trying to call it does it work?

Comment: Run `$s = newRemoteSession '192.168.1.10'` **without parentheses**.

Comment: I get the same results with  `$s = newRemoteSession '192.168.1.10' `  and with   `$s = newRemoteSession -ipAddress '192.168.1.10'`

Comment: The code that you posted should error the first time that it is run.

Comment: Also, if you get the prompt and you do not see the write host, then only a portion of the function code is running.

Comment: Try taking the qualifier off your catch block

Comment: Is your second block your complete script?  the function needs to be defined before the call.  As @JosefZ said, you also need to remove the parenthesis from the function call.    Try writing your script in PowerShell_ISE if possible, then step through debugging.  You also don't need the break in the `catch` block.

Comment: You do not trap `New-PSSession … -ErrorAction Stop` **inside** `Catch` block.

Comment: @JozefZ The Catch is for the first New-PSSession: if it fails (because wrong default credentials) I recall it with credential prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You've found the problems yourself, but since they're common pitfalls, let me elaborate a little:

- **Only ever use `break` / `continue` *inside a loop* (`for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do`) or in the branch handlers of a *`switch` statement*.**

  - Otherwise, *PowerShell looks up the call stack for an enclosing loop* and, in the absence of one, *exits the script*.
  - This is what happened with the `break` in your `catch` block.
- **Do not use `(...)` to enclose the list of function (command) arguments and do not separate arguments with `,`**:

  - In PowerShell, **functions** - just like cmdlets - **are called with *shell-like* syntax, *without parentheses* and with *whitespace-separated* arguments** (`,` is only used to construct an *array* to be passed as a *single* argument)<sup>[1]</sup>
    .

    ```
    # WRONG: method-invocation syntax does NOT apply to *functions*
    # (It *happens* to work *in this case*, however, because only a
    # a *single* argument is passed and the (...) is a no-op in this case,
    # but this syntax should never be used.)
    newRemoteSession('192.168.1.10')

    # OK: Shell-like syntax, which PowerShell calls *argument mode*:
    # Note that the argument needn't be quoted, because it 
    # contains no shell metacharacters.
    # If there were additional arguments, you'd separate them with *whitespace*
    newRemoteSession 192.168.1.10

    # BETTER: You can even use *parameter names* (again, as with cmdlets),
    # which helps readability.
    newRemoteSession -ipAddress 192.168.1.10
    ```
- In PowerShell, **functions must be defined *before* you can call them.**

  - You initially didn't notice, because a *previous* definition of your `newRemoteSession` function happened to exist.

---

<sup>[1] For more information about PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes -
 *argument mode* and *expression mode* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375) of mine.</sup>