# Is (,$arrr) the best way to pass a single array as an argument list to a powershell invoke-command cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, lambda, anonymous-function, invoke, scriptblock

I want to pass an array to a PowerShell script block. This is the accepted method:

```
$arr = 1..4; 
invoke-command -ScriptBlock { Param($li); $li | %{$_}} -ArgumentList (,$arr)
```

From my investigations, these alternatives work too:

```
invoke-command -ScriptBlock { Param($li); $li | %{$_}} -ArgumentList $arr,$arr
invoke-command -ScriptBlock { Param($li); $li | %{$_}} -ArgumentList $arr,$null
```

And the same issue applies when used list this

```
$arr = 1..4; 
$sb = { Param($li); $li | %{$_}}
$sb.Invoke((,$arr))
```

I understand the reason for the (,$arr) syntax is that the -ArgumentList parameter is expecting an array of parameters to pass to the script block, and if it gets a single array as its value, it will unpack the array and pass the contents to the script block as multiple parameters. I credit these answers [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743951/argumentlist-parameter-in-invoke-command-dont-send-all-array) and [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152740/how-do-i-pass-an-array-as-a-parameter-to-another-script) for helping me through this.

The accepted solution looks very ugly to me and I wonder it there is a cleaner way that might be closer to what the designers of PowerShell intended. Please comment.

Perhaps the answer is

```
& $sb $arr.
```

Please comment.

Comment: Why are you using `Invoke-Command` here?

Comment: `$using:` is simpler but works for remote sessions

Comment: Nope.  But usually invoke-command is for remote computers.

Comment: @js2010: this is a simplified example to understand the problem. I am exploring lambda functions and functional programming with powershell, inspired by the accumulate exercise from exercism for powershell. (Google it: it is not fully released yet)

Comment: Thanks for closing: not! I found those older examples too, but to me, the say what to do, but not clearly why.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: i am using Invoke-Command to run a lambda or anonymous  function (in a script block) Is there a better way?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829773/how-to-pass-array-into-anonymous-function) seems to be the most complete explanation of this issue and compares various solutions.

Comment: @NigelDavies Yes, use [the call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#call-operator-) :)