# Get-ChildItem with Multiple Paths via Variable

Tags: powershell

This one stumps me a bit. I generally feel pretty advanced in powershell but I simply dont understand the nuance of this one.

This works

```
$LogFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\windows\temp\*.log,c:\temp\*.log,C:\programdata\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs\*.log
```

Yet what I want to do (and doesnt work) is this:

```
$LogsToGather = "c:\windows\temp\*.log,c:\temp\*.log,C:\programdata\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs\*.log"
$LogFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($LogsToGather)" -Recurse
```

I have tried making the VAR an array, I have tried a number of things with making string. I was able to write around the issue but I am uniquely interested in understanding what data type -path is accepting with that common delineation and be able to create it dynamically.

It seems like a trick that the cmdlet accepts comma delineation. Can it be recreated using some sort of array, hashtable, etc..?

Anyone know?

Comment: The input parameter `-Path` is a string array `[System.String[]]`. So pass your paths also with an array like `[System.String[]]$LogsToGather = @('', '')`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, `$LogsToGather` must be an *array* of strings for your command to work:

```
$LogsToGather = 'c:\windows\temp\*.log', 'c:\temp\*.log', 'C:\programdata\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs\*.log'
```

Note how the array elements, separated by `,`, must be quoted *individually* (see bottom section).

---

`Get-Help` with `-Parameter` is a quick way to examine the data type a given parameter expects:

```
PS> Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter Path

-Path <String[]>
    Specifies a path to one or more locations. Wildcards are permitted. The default location is the current directory (`.`).

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    0
    Default value                Current directory
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName, ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

`String[]` represents an array (`[]`) of `[string]` (`System.String`) instances - see [about_Command_Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_syntax).

For more information on `Get-ChildItem`, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$LogsToGather = "c:\windows\temp\*.log,c:\temp\*.log,C:\programdata\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs\*.log"`

This creates a *single* string that, when passed to `Get-ChildItem`, is *as a whole* interpreted as a *single* path, which obviously won't work.

Note that **specifying the elements of an array *unquoted***, as in:

> `Get-ChildItem -path c:\windows\temp\*.log, c:\temp\*.log, ...`

**is only supported if you pass an array as a *command argument***, not in the context of creating an array with an *expression* such as `$LogsToGather = 'foo', 'bar', ..`

The reason is that **PowerShell has two fundamental parsing modes - *argument mode* and *expression mode***, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375),

Comment: mklement0 your response is nothing short of amazing. Thank you. What I have heard here today will help me now and far into the future. Thanks again!