# Run a command in middle of Write-Host

Tags: powershell, write-host

I have a write-host line that I want to execute a command in the middle of, so the output will be inserted in the middle of the write-host string.

Basically I have a txt file that holds configuration data for a suite of scripts, one of the configurations is the format for dates and time.  For example, there is a configuration for the year format which is 'YYYY' and it is written to $Year.

So what I would like to do is something like this:

```
Write-Host "The year is " Get-Date -Format $Year.ToLower()
```

What I expect to see on my screen when this is ran, is

```
The year is 2019
```

Now I know I can declare another variable with this logic and just have...

```
Write-Host "The year is $NewVariable"
```

...but I was hoping not to create another variable.  This is a dumb-ed down example of my scrip, so I would be creating a lot of variables if I go this rout.  Please note I am using .ToLower() to compensate for the user's input into the configuration text file.

Comment: Google command mode vs expression mode.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776180/powershells-parsing-modes-argument-command-mode-vs-expression-mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to print the year of the **Get-Date** run this:

```bsh
Write-Host "The year is $(Get-Date -Format yyyy)"
```

This way you will always get the year that is generated by **Get-Date**

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had the syntax wrong....I wasn't encapsulating the command properly.  I'm using what you have above with substituting the yyyy for my variable.

Comment: This works too.  `Write-Host The year is (Get-Date -Format yyyy)`