# Argument as variable, instead of directly passing file path, to PowerShell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

> I store file path in variable as below

`$body = E:\Folder\body.txt`

> And try to access it at multiple areas in a PowerShell script like below

`Clear-content -$body`

`Get-content $body.ToString()`

`Set-content $body`

But all these three type of passing arguments are not working. I am getting errors below.

`Cannot find path 'C:\Users\S51\-' because it does not exist`

`You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression`

`Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null`

> Only the traditional

`Clear/Get/Set-content E:\Folder\body.txt` methods work.

Is there any way to assign path to a variable and use them across whole code because I need to access the same path multiple times & if I need to modify the file path in future it requires to modify everywhere. If it is a variable, I can just modify at one place.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you want to have a look at [Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes). Possiby, you want to declare the path variable as `$global:ThePathVariable`

Comment: For a start, it's not seeing your filepath - you should use `Clear-Content -Path $body` and yes, if it;s using a differnt path then you probably need to define `$body` with a wider scope e.g. `$Script:body = E:\Folder\body.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Your symptoms are all explained by the value of `$body` effectively being `$null`.
- The problem is that `E:\Folder\body.txt` *isn't quoted*; if you quote it, your symptoms go away:

```
$body = 'E:\Folder\body.txt'
```

The bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) explains *string literals* in PowerShell, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375) explains PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes, *argument (command)* mode and *expression* mode.

---

**Explanation:**

> I store file path in variable as below
>
> `$body = E:\Folder\body.txt`

**Because what you intend to be *string* `E:\Folder\body.txt` *isn't quoted*, `E:\Folder\body.txt` is interpreted as a *command***, which means:

- `E:\Folder\body.txt` *is opened as a document*, which means that it is opened *asynchronously* in `Notepad.exe` by default.
- Since this operation has no output (return value), variable `$body` is created with value `$null` (strictly speaking, the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` value, which in most contexts behaves like `$null`).

All your symptoms are the result of the value of `$body` effectively being `$null`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below illustrates several ways of using a variable to operate on files.

```bsh
param(
    [string] $body = "$PSScriptRoot\body.txt"    
)

if ((Test-Path -Path $body) -eq $false) {
    New-Item -Path $body -ItemType File
}

function GetContent() {
    Get-Content -Path $body -Verbose
}
GetContent

function GetContentOfFile([string] $filePath) {
    Get-Content -Path $body -Verbose
}
GetContentOfFile -filePath $body

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Clear-Content -Path $body -Verbose }

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param($filepath) Clear-Content -Path $filepath -Verbose } -ArgumentList $body

Set-content -Path $body -Value 'Some content.' -Verbose
```