# Reference argument to a PowerShell class method? [Ref][Uint64]

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell class that I need pass in a reference to a UInt64 Variable and return a value from the Method.  I'm trying to do something like in the code below but it gives me a syntax error.

Maybe I don't need to add ?[ref]? because all variables are references by default in powershell including uint64?  but i just wasn't sure if this is true.... If I follow normal C-language convention then the method gets a copy of the argument not the actual reference to the variable.  I seem to recall something in C# about boxing and unboxing int types... [boxing and unboxing c# int type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) How does it work for boxing Int for Powershell class methods?

```
class PowerHe11 {

    # Constructor
    PowerHe11() {
    }

    [void]AccessChannel(
        [UInt64]$ichan,
        [UInt64]$idata,
        [UInt64]$isize,
        [UInt64]$ireal,    
        [ref][UInt64]$otimeout,
        [ref][UInt64]$odata,
        [ref][UInt64]$ochan,
        [ref][UInt64]$osize

    ) {                  
        $osize = 64;  #Return this value to caller of method
    }
}
```

Error message is:

```
At C:\Users\wmoore\Documents\fpga\zynq_pl\run_ps1\Untitled1.ps1:13 char:11
+         [ref][UInt64]$otimeout,
+              ~~~~~~~~
Multiple type constraints are not allowed on a method parameter.
At C:\Users\wmoore\Documents\fpga\zynq_pl\run_ps1\Untitled1.ps1:14 char:14
+         [ref][UInt64]$odata,
+              ~~~~~~~~
Multiple type constraints are not allowed on a method parameter.
At C:\Users\wmoore\Documents\fpga\zynq_pl\run_ps1\Untitled1.ps1:15 char:14
+         [ref][UInt64]$ochan,
+              ~~~~~~~~
Multiple type constraints are not allowed on a method parameter.
At C:\Users\wmoore\Documents\fpga\zynq_pl\run_ps1\Untitled1.ps1:16 char:14
+         [ref][UInt64]$osize
+              ~~~~~~~~
Multiple type constraints are not allowed on a method parameter.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MultipleTypeConstraintsOnMethodParam
```

Comment: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-ref.html

Answer (score 4):

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65130083/45375) shows the solution; let me add an explanation and background information:

[about_Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Ref) is the official help topic.

The short of it:

- **`[ref]`'s primary purpose is to support `ref` and `out` parameters in *.NET methods***; e.g., to call the [`System.Int32.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32.TryParse) method, use the following:

  - `[int] $int = 0; [int]::TryParse('42', [ref] $int)`
  - Note that the **variable's type must match the type expected by the .NET method**, and that the only way to create a variable in PowerShell is to also assign it a value (even if that value is irrelevant, as is the case with the `out` parameter at hand); the `[ref]` cast is required (analogous to the need to use `ref` or `out` in C#.
  - You may pass `[ref] $null` if you're not interested in the value being assigned by the method.
- **While you *can* use it in PowerShell code, doing so is *awkward***, as your example shows:

  - **PowerShell code that receives a `[ref]` argument must refer to its value via the `.Value` property**, as your answer shows.
  - **You *cannot type-constrain* such a parameter**, so you lose type safety.

    - Note that in *function and scripts* - as opposed to custom-class *methods* - it is *syntactically allowed, but pointless* to use both `[ref]` and a target data type (such as `[ref][UInt64]$otimeout` in your example), because the latter is effectively *ignored*; e.g.:

      - `function foo { param([ref] [int] $p) $p.Value += '!' }; $bar = 'none'; foo ([ref] $bar); $bar`
      - The call succeeds and `$bar` contains `'none!'`, which implies that the `[int]` type constraint was ignored.
  - Calling scripts and functions requires [argument-mode syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375) (shell-like, whitespace-separated arguments, bareword strings allowed), making the `[ref]`-cast invocation more awkward by requiring `(...)` around the argument, as shown above (`foo ([ref] $bar)`).
  - With respect to use in custom PowerShell `class`es, note that **[PowerShell's class support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) is - by design - *not* on par with that of OO-focused languages such as `C#`**; that said, enhancements are planned; unfortunately, even the limited feature set still has problem as of PowerShell 7.1 - see [GitHub issue #6652](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652).

---

**Technical background on `[ref]`**:

**`[ref]`**, unlike `ref` in C#, is ***not* a language keyword**: it **is a *type***, namely [`[System.Management.Automation.PSReference]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSReference) (whose [*type accelerator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators) is `[ref]`).

As such, an expression such as `[ref] $var` is a *cast* that implicitly *constructs a `[ref]` instance*, which is required to bind to a `[ref]`-typed parameter.

**Caveats**:

- There is **parser magic involved in a `[ref]` cast**, because you *cannot* directly use the normally equivalent `[ref]::new($var)` constructor expression as an alternative to cast `[ref] $var`.

  - PowerShell needs magic to know that `$var` refers to a *variable object itself* rather than to the variable's *value*, as is normally the case in an expression - and the latter is indeed what happens with `[ref]::new($var)` - `$var`'s *value* is wrapped in a `[ref]` instance.
  - The true constructor equivalent of `[ref] $var` is `[ref]::new((Get-Variable var))`

```sh
# BROKEN: Do not use a constructor - [ref]::new($int) - 
#         in lieu of a cast - [ref] $int
PS> [int] $int = 0; $null = [int]::TryParse('42', [ref]::new($int)); $int
0 # !! $int was NOT updated, because its *value* was wrapped in a [ref] instance
```

- **It generally only makes sense to use a `[ref]` cast with a *variable (object)* operand**.

  - PowerShell lets you pass any value as the operand, which technically works, but makes no sense unless you explicitly save *the `[ref]` instance* in a variable, pass *it* as the argument, and then use the `[ref]` instance's `.Value` property to access the updated value:

```sh
# Save a [ref] instance in a variable, pass it, then use .Value to get the 
# updated value.
PS> [ref] $intRef = 0; $null = [int]::TryParse('42', $intRef); $intRef.Value
42
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class powerhe11 {

# Constructor
powerhe11() {
}

    [void]AccessChannel(
        [ref]$ichan

    ) {         
         $ichan.value = 0xbeef;
         
         Write-Host("ichan: {0}" -f $ichan.value)
    }

}



[UInt64]$dude = 0

$ser = [gvmuart]::new()

$ser.AccessChannel([ref]$dude);


Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green "DUDE: $dude"
```