# Provide an implementation of a C# abstract class in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-7.0, intacct

I'm trying to create a PowerShell-class implementation of an [abstract class](https://github.com/Intacct/intacct-sdk-net/blob/master/Intacct.SDK/Functions/AbstractFunction.cs)' function:

```
class ReadList : Intacct.SDK.Functions.AbstractFunction {

    [string]$ObjectName
    
    ReadList ([string]$ObjectName) {
        $this.ObjectName = $ObjectName
    }

    [void] WriteXml ( [Intacct.SDK.Xml.IaXmlWriter]$xml ) {

        $xml.WriteStartDocument()
        
        $xml.WriteStartElement("get_list")
        $xml.WriteAttributeString("object",$this.ObjectName)    
        $xml.WriteEndElement() # </get_list> 
    
        $xml.WriteEndDocument()
        $xml.Flush()
        $xml.Close()

    }

}
```

When I attempt to use it, I get a run-time exception:

> Error during creation of type "ReadList". Error message: Method 'WriteXml' in type 'ReadList' from assembly 'PowerShell Class Assembly, Version=1.0.0.1,
> | Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

I've tried adding the `ref` tag:

```
[void] WriteXml ( [Intacct.SDK.Xml.IaXmlWriter][ref]$xml ) {
```

But I get a different error:

> Multiple type constraints are not allowed on a method parameter.

Am I doing something wrong, or is what I'm trying to do not supported?

Comment: Is `WriteXml` defined in `Intacct.SDK.Functions.AbstractFunction` as well?

Comment: No, it's defined in the `IFunction` interface: https://github.com/Intacct/intacct-sdk-net/blob/master/Intacct.SDK/Functions/IFunction.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is not supported. I have not been able to find a good workaround, or a resource that succinctly explains it.

Technically the second implementation is correct, but as per the error PowerShell does not support multiple type constraints on a method parameter<sup>[1]</sup>.
Normally this isn't the end of the world. The problem is when inheriting from an abstract class, the class must define all of the abstract methods <sup>[2]</sup>, so a method with signature `WriteXml (ref IaXmlWriter <ParameterName>)` must be defined. Anything else gives the `Method 'WriteXml' ... does not have an implementation.`

Even if PowerShell supported multiple type constraints, I don't think this would work as intended because the `c#` is not the same as PowerShell's `[ref]` - `[ref]` was created to support COM Objects and the documentation explicitly states it can't be used to type-cast class members<sup>[3]</sup>.

The only workaround I'm aware of that might work here is writing the `ReadList` class definition in `c#`, and adding to PowerShell via `Add-Type`<sup>[4]</sup>... not great.

All this is beyond the scope of my knowledge; maybe there is a good solution and someone with more know-how can correct me.

---

**References**
**[1]** [SO post that touches on this and [ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129689/reference-argument-to-a-powershell-class-method-refuint64/) (same as below)

Looking at `$Error.Exception.StackTrace`, [**`System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create`**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management.Automation/System/Management/Automation/ScriptBlock.cs,26) is raising the exception. Couldn't go further with PowerShell 5.1 but PowerShell Core files include a check for class method parameters [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/SemanticChecks.cs#L316) which points to the [**`MultipleTypeConstraintsOnMethodParam`**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/resources/ParserStrings.resx#L1360) exception that gets raised.

[**`Scripting.Classes.BasicParsing.Tests.ps1`**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/test/powershell/Language/Classes/Scripting.Classes.BasicParsing.Tests.ps1#L324) checks multiple types will raise a `MultipleTypeConstraintsOnMethodParam` exception.

**[2]** *Derived classes of the abstract class must implement all abstract methods.*
[Abstract and Sealed Classes and Class Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members)

**[3]** [SO post that touches on this and multiple type constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129689/reference-argument-to-a-powershell-class-method-refuint64/) (same as above)

*The PSReference type is not supported with class members*
[about_Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.1)

**[4]** [Add a .NET type to a session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7.1#example-1--add-a--net-type-to-a-session)

---

**Edit**
To elaborate on the `Add-Type` solution

- Use `ReferencedAssemblies` to pass in `Intacct.SDK.dll` and dependent assemblies.
- Load these assemblies using `[Reflection.Assembly]`

Use `Load()` when specifying version or `LoadFromPartialName()` with just the name, `LoadFrom()` when specifying the path.

```
$Assemblies = @(
    'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
    'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
) |
foreach {
    [Reflection.Assembly]::Load($_)
}

$Assemblies += @(
    "$pwd/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll"
    "$pwd/Intacct.SDK.dll"
) | foreach {
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($_)
}

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -ReferencedAssemblies $Assemblies
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to the same conclusion that I would need to create a C# class definition and import it.

```
Push-Location ~/Desktop

$Source = @"
using Intacct.SDK.Functions;
using Intacct.SDK.Xml;

public class GetList : Intacct.SDK.Functions.AbstractFunction
{
    public string ObjectName;

    public GetList (string objectName) 
    {
        this.ObjectName = objectName;
    }

    public override void WriteXml( ref Intacct.SDK.Xml.IaXmlWriter xml )
    {
        xml.WriteStartDocument();        
        xml.WriteStartElement("get_list");
        xml.WriteEndDocument();
        xml.Flush();
    }
}
"@
    
# netstandard and ReaderWriter are located in `$PSHOME`; others on Desktop
$Assemblies = @(
    'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
    'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
    "$pwd/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll"
    "$pwd/Intacct.SDK.dll"
)

# using ReferenceAssemblies based on a suggestion from the PowerShell Slack channel
$Type = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -ReferencedAssemblies $Assemblies -PassThru

$GetList = [GetList]::new('something')
$GetList
```

which generates errors:

```
Add-Type: getlist.ps1:37:9
Line |
  37 |  $Type = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Could not load file or assembly 'Intacct.SDK, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The parameter is incorrect.  (0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```