# Pass Class Property by Reference in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell ISE on Windows 11

```
PS C:\Users\malcolm> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                              
----                           -----                                                              
PSVersion                      5.1.22000.282                                                      
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                            
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                            
BuildVersion                   10.0.22000.282                                                     
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                    
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I need to pass a class property as reference in PowerShell.

For example like this:

```
Function Add-Five
{
    param([ref]$value)
    $value.Value+=5
}

$a = 5
Add-Five -value ([ref]$a)
Write-Host "A = $a"
```

As expected this outputs **10**

However, if I do this:

```
class MyClass
{
    $a
}
Function Add-Five
{
    param([ref]$value)
    $value.Value+=5
}
    
$class = New-Object MyClass
$class.a = 5
Add-Five -value ([ref]$class.a)
Write-Host "A = $($class.a)"
```

The output is **5.**

As a workaround I can do this :

```
Function Add-FiveSpecial
{
    param($className,$propertyName)
    (Get-Variable -Name $className).Value.$propertyName += 5    
}

Add-FiveSpecial -className "class" -propertyName "a"
Write-Host "A = $($class.a)"
```

Which outputs **10**

Is there a way to get [ref] to work with class properties?

Comment: Can the class property be of the type `ref` ? It should work that way. Also, why not have a instance method to do what the function is doing ?

Comment: Using ref as class property does work, but then as far as I can tell I can't set the type of data in the class property if I want. In my actual program it is an instance method, but I have the same issue there. When not a class property I can still have the value as type Int32 for example and pass as reference, but not as class property.

Comment: Having `Add-Five` as an instance method of your class is not an option?

Comment: Why not pass the `[MyClass]` instance as the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **primary purpose of the [`[ref]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSReference) class** (it is *not* a *keyword*) is to **facilitate calling *.NET APIs* that have `ref` and `out` parameters**.

**`[ref]` is rarely used in pure PowerShell code and best avoided there**, because it deviates from how parameters are usually passed, is syntactically cumbersome, and has pitfalls, such as the one at hand.

In a nutshell:

- **`[ref]` only works meaningfully with a PowerShell *variable***, where it truly creates an alias name for the given variable *object*, so that getting and setting the variable value targets the very same variable object, irrespective of whether you use the original name or the alias.
- While PowerShell lets you cast *any* expression to `[ref]`, with anything *other* than a variable it functions *like a regular assignment*, and is therefore ineffective.<sup>[1]</sup>

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65147955/45375) has more in-depth information about `[ref]`.

Simplified examples:

**Correct use of `[ref]`: with a *variable*:**

- Illustration without the use of a function:

```sh
PS> $foo = 42; $bar = [ref] $foo; ++$bar.Value; $foo
43  # OK, incrementing the .Value of $bar updated the value of $foo
```

<sup>**Syntax note**: The variable to alias must be cast *directly* to `[ref]`. Therefore, trying to use it as a variable type constraint does *not* work: <del>`[ref] $bar = $foo`</del></sup>

- Real-world example with a .NET API, [`[int]::TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32.TryParse), whose second parameter is an `out` parameter:

```sh
# Declare a variable to use with [ref]
# Note: No need to type the variable.
$intVal = $null

# Pass the variable via [ref] to receive the out parameter value
# of [int]::TryParse()
$null = [int]::TryParse('42', [ref] $intVal)

# $intVal now contains 42
```

**Pointless use of `[ref]`: with *any other* expression**, such as an object *property*:<sup>[1]</sup>

```sh
PS> $foo = [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 42 }; $bar = [ref] $foo.prop; ++$bar.Value; $foo.prop
42  # !! $foo's value was NOT updated.
```

---

Therefore **your options** are:

- If `Add-Five` cannot be modified, use an *auxiliary variable* to act as the by-reference argument.

  ```sh
    class MyClass{ $a = 0 }

    Function Add-Five {
      param([ref]$value)
      $value.Value+=5
    }

    $myObj = [MyClass]::new()

    # Create and use an aux. variable.
    $aux = $myObj.a
    Add-Five ([ref] $aux)

    # Update the property via the updated aux. variable.
    $myObj.a = $aux
    # myObj.a now contains 5
  ```
- Otherwise:

  - Let `Add-Five` *output* (return) the new value and assign it to the property:

    ```sh
    class MyClass{ $a = 0 }

    Function Add-Five {
      param($value) # regular parameter (variable)
      $value + 5    # output the new value
    }

    $myObj = [MyClass]::new()

    # Pass the property value and assign back to it.
    $myObj.a = Add-Five $myObj.a 
    # myObj.a now contains 5
    ```
  - As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) suggests, pass a `[MyClass]` instance *as a whole* to `Add-Five` and let it update the property there:

    ```sh
    class MyClass{ $a = 0 }

    Function Add-Five {
      param([MyClass] $MyObj) # expect a [MyClass] instance as a whole
      $MyObj.a += 5           # update the property directly
    }

    $myObj = [MyClass]::new()

    Add-Five $myObj
    # myObj.a now contains 5
    ```

---

<sup>[1] There's another - albeit exotic - use of `[ref]` shown in the conceptual [about_Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Ref#references-and-scopes) help topic, but it doesn't relate to creating a reference to a value *stored elsewhere*; instead, it uses a `[ref]` instance as an *alternative* to a regular variable to allow it to be updated *from descendant scopes* in a syntactically more convenient manner (with a regular variable, you'd have to use the `Get-Variable` / `Set-Variable` cmdlets).</sup>