# Split a string into an Object array

Tags: arrays, powershell, command-line-arguments, select-object

I have this string in PowerShell:

```
$filter = "Name;Server;Mounted;ObjectCategory;Guid;WhenChangedUTC;WhenCreatedUTC;ObjectState"
```

I want to split it to get an object array, I tried:

```
$stringArray = $filter.Split(';')
```

but it's a string array.

At the end I would like to call:

```
... | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Command'; Expression = { "Insert" } }, $filterObjectArray
```

The $filterObjectArray doesn't work when it's a string array.

But it works if `$filterObjectArray = 'Name', 'Server'` ...

The problem is my custom property called **Command** because if I only use :

```
    ... | Select-Object -Property $filterObjectArray
```

it works.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your `-Property` argument must be passed as a *flat* array, which requires use of an *expression***:

```sh
# Note: Target parameter -Property is positionally implied.
Select-Object (, @{Name = 'Command'; Expression={ "Insert" }} + $filterObjectArray)
```

Note:

- Because an *expression* is required that is to serve as a *command argument*, it must be enclosed in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--).
- `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), is used to wrap the script block (`{ ... }`) in a single-element array so that applying the `+` operator on it performs *array concatenation*, which means that the elements of the RHS array, `$filterObjectArray`, directly become elements of the resulting array, resulting in the necessary *flat* array of calculated properties and property names.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `@{Name = 'Command'; Expression = { "Insert" } }, $filterObjectArray`

This argument, parsed in argument mode, results in a *nested* array: the first element is the script block (`{ ... }`), and the *second and last* element is the `$filterObjectArray` array *as a whole*, which is why the names stored in it weren't recognized.

Note that in argument mode - one of PowerShell's two [fundamental parsing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375) - only a small subset of operators can be used, such as `,` and `@`, the [splatting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting); to use others, such as `+`, a grouping expression (`(...)`) is needed, as shown (or, for using the output from entire *statements* as arguments, `$(...)` or `@(...)`)