# How can I use IF using a function properly?

Tags: powershell

The function below returns a result, but when I specify the value in an IF statement, it just return "Yes" whatever I put in the -eq value.

```
function GetRemoteLogonStatus ($computer = 'localhost') { 
if (Test-Connection $computer -Count 2 -Quiet) { 
    try { 
        $user = $null 
        $user = gwmi -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $computer | select -ExpandProperty username -ErrorAction Stop 
        } 
    catch { "Not logged on"; return } 
    try { 
        if ((Get-Process logonui -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop) -and ($user)) { 
            "Workstation locked by $user" 
            } 
        } 
    catch { if ($user) { "$user logged on" } } 
    } 
else { "$computer Offline" } 
}
```

```
if (getremotelogonstatus -eq "blah blah blah")
{
write-host "Yes"
}
Else
{
Write-Host "no"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For output from a *command* (such as `GetRemoteLogonStatus`) to participate in an *expression*, the command call (including its arguments, if any) must be enclosed in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

```bash
if ((GetRemoteLogonStatus) -eq "blah blah blah") {
  "Yes"
}
Else {
  "No"
}
```

Note:

- If the command outputs *multiple* objects, the `-eq` operator will act as a *filter* and, instead of returning `$true` or `$false`, will return the *subarray of matching elements* - see the conceptual [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators) help topic.
- To read more about PowerShell's two fundamental *parsing modes* - *argument* (command) mode  vs. *expression* mode - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375).

Enclosure in **`(...)` is also needed** for **using a command's output as an *argument*** to another command (the example is somewhat contrived in that explicit use of `Write-Output` is rarely necessary):

```bash
# Pass the output from GetRemoteLogonStatus as an argument to Write-Output
Write-Output -InputObject (GetRemoteLogonStatus)
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`getremotelogonstatus -eq "blah blah blah"`

- Because this snippet is parsed in *argument* mode, it invokes command `getremotelogonstatus` and *passes `-eq` and `blah blah blah` as arguments to it*.
- Since your command neither formally [declares parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters) (with a `param(...)` block) nor processes the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) containing unbound positional arguments, these arguments are effectively *ignored*.