# .GetType().FullName or subtraction doesn't work on a function call directly in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have on my win10 Pro machine with Powershell 7.1 following problem:
Here is the script:

```
function hoursInSeconds ([String] $hour){
    # $hour expected format: hh:mm:ss
    $par = $hour.Split(":")
    $secs = [int]$par[0] * 3600 + [int]$par[1] * 60 + [int]$par[2]
    return $secs
}
$a = "17:55:11"
$b = "18:06:00"
$c = hoursInSeconds($b) - hoursInSeconds($a)
Write-Host "c:" $c
$aSec = hoursInSeconds($a)
$bSec = hoursInSeconds($b)
$d = $bSec - $aSec
$bSec.GetType().FullName
hoursInSeconds($a).GetType().FullName
Write-Host "a, b, aSec, bSec, d:" $a $b $aSec $bSec $d
```

Because the subtruction of the function calls didn't work as I had expected 
I had expected (64511 - 65160 = 649, instead the result was "c: 65160"), 
I tried to find why, looking at the format of the function call:

```
hoursInSeconds($a).GetType().FullName
```

But then I received another error. 
Here is the whole output:

```
c: 65160
System.Int32
a, b, aSec, bSec, d: 17:55:11 18:06:00 64511 65160 649
Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At D:\DEVELOP\Powershell\TimeFunctions_1.ps1:4 char:5
+     $secs = [int]$par[0] * 3600 + [int]$par[1] * 60 + [int]$par[2]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

So, there are two questions, probably depending from one another:

1. Why doesn't work the subtruction this way? and
2. Why doesn't work the .GetType().FullName this way?

Some idea? 
Thanks

Comment: OK, in my opinion it's a bit strange. What if I was calling two different functions instead? The compiler should realize that I want to substruct two different values...But in any case good to know this behaviour :-) Probably I have to get used to this syntax :-) Because it doesn't even complain when I use this syntax: hoursInSeconds($a) instead of this one: (hoursInSeconds $a). Thanks again

Comment: `hoursInSeconds($a)` is the same as `hoursInSeconds ($a)`, which is the same as `hoursInSeconds $a` - i.e., you're passing the value of `$a` as an argument. _This equivalence is a happy accident_ that (a) only works because the `(` tells the parser that it is the start of an argument, in lieu of whitespace and (b) falls apart once you try to pass _multiple_ arguments using pseudo method syntax, e.g., `hoursInSeconds($a, $b)`, which is _not_ the same as `hoursInSeconds $a $b`, which is how you must pass _two_ arguments in PowerShell; `,` constructs _arrays_ that are passed as a _single_ arg.

Comment: Indeed, if you want your PowerShell code to work as intended, you'll have to use this _argument-mode_ syntax for calling _commands_. PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes, discussed in the answer, is what this all comes down to, which also explains why you need to enclose command calls _as a whole_ in `(...)` so they can participate in _expressions_. Of course, that includes the ability to call _different_ functions in a single expression; that in your case you're calling the _same_ function is incidental to the problem.

Comment: OK, I think I understood now that I have to go much deeper into this themes like parsing modes and such... Thanks again @mklement0, you've been very helpful to me:-)

Comment: Glad to hear it,@delaflota; my pleasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a **syntax problem**:

```bash
hoursInSeconds($b) - hoursInSeconds($a)  # WRONG
hoursInSeconds($a).GetType().FullName    # WRONG
```

<sup>Note: *Wrong* in this context means: the syntax is *formally* valid, but *doesn't do what you expect*.</sup>

It should be:

```bash
(hoursInSeconds $b) - (hoursInSeconds $a)  # -> 649
(hoursInSeconds $a).GetType().FullName     # -> 'System.Int32'
```

Note the corrections:

- The function calls *as a whole* are now enclosed in `(...)`.

  - In PowerShell terms, a function call is a *command* , and **for commands to participate in an *expression*** - such as use of `-`, the subtraction *operator*, or a *method call* and/or *property access* - such as `.GetType()` and `.FullName` - **they must be enclosed in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375) for more information.
- The **arguments** to pass to your functions are now **separated with *spaces*** from the function name; similarly, spaces (rather than `,`) would have to be used to separate *multiple arguments*.

In short: **PowerShell commands (functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs) must be invoked *like shell commands* - `foo arg1 arg2` - *not* like C# methods -

`foo('arg1', 'arg2')`**.

**If you use `,` rather than spaces to separate arguments, you'll construct an *array* that a command sees as a *single argument***.

To prevent accidental use of method syntax, you can use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its other effects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.

---

As for **how your commands were interpreted**:

- Your `hoursInSeconds($b) - hoursInSeconds($a)` call is accidentally parsed as a *single* invocation of `hoursInSeconds`, with the value of `$b`, verbatim `-` and `hoursInSeconds` and finally the value of `$a` *all* passed as *arguments* to that single invocation - since your function doesn't enforce what (extra) arguments are passed, they went unnoticed, so in effect only `hoursInSeconds $b` was executed.

  - The reason is that this call is parsed in *argument* mode (command mode), one of PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes (the other being *expression* mode), due to starting with the *name of a command* - again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375)
  - For a comprehensive discussion of how PowerShell parses unquoted tokens in argument mode, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).
- Your `hoursInSeconds($a).GetType().FullName` call is parsed as follows: `($a).GetType().FullName` is evaluated *first*, and since `$a` is a *string*, the result is verbatim string `System.String`, which is then passed to function `hoursInSeconds` as an argument - which fails, because the argument isn't in the expected `"HH:mm:ss"` string format.

---

As an aside: You can **simplify your function** with the help of the `[timespan]` ([`System.TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan)) class:

```bash
function hoursInSeconds ([string] $timeOfDay){
  [int] ([timespan] $timeOfDay).TotalSeconds
}
```

Note that `return` isn't necessary in this simple case; in PowerShell, you only ever need `return` for *control flow*, not for *data output*. Any command or expression whose output is neither captured, redirected, or sent through the pipeline to another command is *implicitly* output - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for more information.