# Getting a better understanding of the dot notation in Powershell

Tags: powershell, object

Why can I do this:

**Example 1**

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | 
  ? IPv4DefaultGateWay -NE $null
```

and

**Example 2**

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | 
  ? {$_.IPv4DefaultGateWay -NE $null -and $_.NetAdapter.Status -EQ "Up"}
```

but not this

**Example 3**

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | 
  ? IPv4DefaultGateWay -NE $null -and NetAdapter.Status -EQ "Up"
```

The error message I get is as follows:

```
Where-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:2 char:3
+   ? IPv4DefaultGateWay -NE $null -and NetAdapter.Status -EQ "Up"
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

but obviously the Where-Object cmdlet is capable of handling compound conditions with the use of -and and -or, so the error message is confusing.

**ALSO**, Why can I do this

**Example 4**

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | 
  ? {$_.IPv4DefaultGateWay -NE $null -and $_.NetAdapter.Status -EQ "Up"} |
  % {
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        ComputerName = $_.ComputerName
        IPAddress = $_.IPv4Address.IPv4Address
    }
  }
```

but not be able to do this

**Example 5**

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | 
  ? {$_.IPv4DefaultGateWay -NE $null -and $_.NetAdapter.Status -EQ "Up"} |
  Select-Object ComputerName, IPv4Address.IPv4Address
```

My objective is being met by using Example 4, but that's not what I am really asking here - It is the convention of addressing properties and properties of properties that I am more concerned about here!

Comment: the 1st example is using a special mode of the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet that allows ONE property to be dealt with. the 2nd is the full-function version of the same cmdlet.

Comment: You can only refer to the property as a whole meaning, that when you try to *dot reference* (*dot notation*) the property, one, its incorrect syntax if not in a script block (*and someone correct me if I'm wrong* ). Then two, you're trying to evaluate the properties of that value which have none besides it being the value itself. That's why when it's in a script block, you use *dot notation* to reference the property, and filter against that. In summary: *`Where-Object` is expecting properties as a whole and not the value it holds when filtering*.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - You said "Where-Object is expecting properties as a whole and not the value it holds when filtering.", however in Ex1, ?/Where/Where-Object can filter on IPv4DefaultGateway, but in Ex3 it errors out when NetAdapter.Status -EQ "Up" is added. IPv4DefaultGateway and NetAdapter are both properties of NetIPConfiguration, yet the behavior is different. That is the crux of my question. Why does Ex1 work without the $_ prefix, and Ex3 fails? I know that $_ is the Current Object passed in from the left of the pipe symbol, its why it can be implicitly referenced in Ex1 but not in Ex3?

Comment: It's just bad interpretation on my end. The property as a whole, contains the value, which `-Property` filters for. That is the point of `-FilterScript` for child properties within a property. `? name -eq 'something'` defaults to `-Property` which expects a property *as is*. This is why `-FilterScript` exists to allow more complex requirements to be done, even if that includes referencing a child property of a property; which seems to have been made intentionally this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The differences ultimately stem from PowerShell's two fundamental *parsing modes***, explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375); in short:

- ***argument* mode** is shell-like, for invoking *commands* with whitespace-separated *arguments*, with support for *unquoted* strings.
- ***expression* mode** works like a traditional programming language, with quoted strings, operators, loop constructs, ...

In both your examples, *commands* are invoked (more specifically, *cmdlets*, namely [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (whose built-in aliases are `?` and `where`) and [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (whose built-in alias is `select`), so what is being passed to them is parsed in *argument* mode:

- `Where-Object IPv4DefaultGateWay -NE $null` uses argument mode for **[simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax)**, i.e. a lower-ceremony argument-mode alternative to an expression-mode [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), also available with the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet.

  - The syntax is *simpler*:

    - No need for enclosure in `{ ... }`
    - No need to refer to the input object at hand via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), just using the property name by itself is enough.
  - But it is *limited*:

    - You can only perform a *single operation*, on a *single property*.<sup>[1]</sup>
    - That property must be an *immediate* property (e.g., `IPv4DefaultGateWay`, not a *nested* one (e.g. `NetAdapter.Status`) - more on that below.
- `Select-Object` too has the constraint that a given property name must be an *immediate* property.

  - The only way to work around that is via a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties), implemented via a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) whose `Expression` entry contains a script block that calculates the property value for each input object - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375).

---

**Why *nested* property access (e.g., `NetAdapter.Status`) *isn't* supported in argument-parsing mode:**

An *argument* such as `NetAdapter.Status` - whether quoted or not - is passed as a *string* to commands, and `Where-Object` and `Select-Object` interpret such a string passed to their `-Property` parameter as the *verbatim* name of a property, not as a *nested* property-access *expression*.

That is, the equivalent of the following command, where `NetAdapter.Status` is parsed in *argument mode*:

```sh
Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetAdapter.Status
```

is the following *expression-mode* property access:

```sh
Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed |
  ForEach-Object { $_.'NetAdapter.Status' }
```

Note the `'...'` around `NetAdapter.Status`, showing that this name was used *verbatim* as the single and immediate property name on the input object (which doesn't work as intended).

---

**Design rationale**:

The challenge is that in *argument* mode no distinction is made between `NetAdapter.Status` and `'NetAdapter.Status'` and `"NetAdapter.Status"` - the target command sees verbatim `NetAdapter.Status` in all cases, so - unlike in *expression* mode - the original quoting / non-quoting cannot serve to distinguish these argument forms.

However, arguably it is much more useful for cmdlets that specifically accept property names (parameter `-Property`) to interpret arguments such as `NetAdapter.Status` as *nested* property accessor, given that property names with *embedded* `.` chars. are rare.

Changing this behavior would be a *breaking* change, however, given that the following currently works, but wouldn't any longer:

```sh
PS> '{ "foo.bar": 42 }' | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object foo.bar

foo.bar
-------
     42
```

---

<sup>[1] The two parsing modes are so different that it would be impossible to recreate all expression-mode features in argument mode; you couldn't model the complexities of expression mode with command arguments (parameter definitions). Simplified syntax is a compromise aimed at making simple, but common use cases syntactically easier.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and well-explained answer (with references to boot)! It never ceases to amaze me about the number of people who are experts in their areas who freely contribute their knowledge to educate the rest of us! Much obliged!!

Comment: I am glad to hear the answer is useful, @hsbatra; my pleasure. Receiving such nice feedback certainly helps with staying motivated.