# Second function inside an if with an -And doesn't get executed (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have the following functions

```
function checkA {
  Write-Host "Checking A"
  return $true
}

function checkB {
  Write-Host "Checking B"
  return $true
}
```

Now, in the main program I use both functions like:

```
if(checkA -And checkB){
  Write-Host "Checks are ok"
  return
}
```

I'm not getting the checkB Write-Host output and the IDE says the function is not even referenced when used like this.

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Related: [PowerShell's parsing modes: argument (command) mode vs. expression mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48776180/7571258)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell is treating the `-And` as a parameter to `checkA` and `checkB` as the value of the parameter.  Since `checkB` is not recognised as a function here, it is never called.

If you wrap the function calls in brackets, it should work as expected:

```
if((checkA) -And (checkB)){
  Write-Host "Checks are ok"
  return
}
```

Comment: Yeah okey I have to take care with that. My real problem had one argument for both checkA and checkB functions so I had a bit of a mess. However wrapping it up in functions seems to work. Thanks!