# How to pass Powershell Class method or function return value to Set-Content -Path

Tags: powershell, return-value

```
class getVar {
    static [string]pdConfigVarGetMethod($var = "") {

        $configFilePath = "$Env:PD_SCRIPTS\pdConfigurationFile.ps1"
        $configFileContent = Get-Content -Path $configFilePath
    
        foreach ($line in $configFileContent) {
            $lineVar = $line -split (':::')
            if ($lineVar[0] -eq $var) {
                return $lineVar[1]
            }
        }
    
        return ""
    }   
}

$path = [getVar]::pdConfigVarGetMethod("PD_SCRIPTS")
Set-Location -Path $path
```

The above code works. What I want to understand is why this won't work:

```
Set-Location -Path [getVar]::pdConfigVarGetMethod("PD_SCRIPTS")
```

I used a class method because I learned that PS function return values have no contract. A class method's return value is loosly typed and can be relied upon to return only what I asked it to return with the proper type.

So why then doesn't the method call resolve into a string value that Set-Content -Path can understand???

I get the error:

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'PD_SCRIPTS'.
At C:\Users\Paul.Defina\Documents\PowershellScripts\ScriptDir.ps1:11 char:1
+ Set-Location -Path [getVar]::pdConfigVarGetMethod("PD_SCRIPTS")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

I expected:

```
Set-Location -Path [getVar]::pdConfigVarGetMethod("PD_SCRIPTS")
```

to work the same as:

```
$path = [getVar]::pdConfigVarGetMethod("PD_SCRIPTS")
Set-Location -Path $path
```

Answer (score 1):

**In *argument* [parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), `[` is *not* a metacharacter**, and therefore what in *expression* (parsing) mode is **a *type literal*, such as `[getVar]`, is *not* recognized as such** and is simply interpreted *verbatim*.

Therefore, you must **enclose your expression *in parentheses* - [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)** - in order for it to be recognized as such:

```
Set-Location -Path ([getVar]::pdConfigVarGetMethod("PD_SCRIPTS"))
```

<sup>As an aside: `-Path` interprets its argument as a *wildcard expression*. If you know your path to be a *literal* one, it is more robust to use `-LiteralPath`.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `Set-Location -Path [getVar]::pdConfigVarGetMethod("PD_SCRIPTS")`

While `[` *isn't* a metacharacter in argument mode, `(` *is*, and -despite there being no space before `(`, PowerShell considers the `(...)` expression to be a *separate argument*, so that in effect you passed *two* arguments:

- Verbatim `[getVar]::pdConfigVarGetMethod`
- Verbatim `PD_SCRIPTS`, which is what the *expression* `("PD_SCRIPTS")` evaluated to.

This unexpected extra argument caused  [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) to report an error.

By contrast:

> `$path = [getVar]::pdConfigVarGetMethod("PD_SCRIPTS")`
> `Set-Location -Path $path`

This *did* work, because in the context of an [*assignment* statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators), `[getVar]` *is* recognized as a type literal, because the RHS of the assignment *starting with* a `[` causes it to be parsed in *expression* mode.

**In short:**

- **In a given parsing context, it is the *first token* that determines which mode is entered**:

  - If the first token of a statement is an *unquoted name* (symbolic identifier) - such as `Set-Location` - it is assumed to refer to a *command*, and *argument mode* is entered.
  - Otherwise, it is assumed to be an *expression*, and *expression mode* is entered - this therefore includes tokens that start with `[`, so that they're recognized as part of type literals.
- **You can create a *new* parsing context with [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)**, and also [`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) (primarily for use inside `"..."`) and [`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--).

See also:

- The conceptual conceptual [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) help topic.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375), which provides a concise summary.